# why are the hair particles showing up on the origin point?

Tags: particles, hair

Ive tried many of the fixes ....but am still unable to solve this....im using 2.90.1 version and this has been happening to me since 2.83.

solutions ive tried:

- applying scale and rotation
- turning on use modifier stack in emission settings(solution found on stack exchange)

[image: this is what happens when i add a particle hair system to any object]

[blend file download](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/eDB1oVxE)

[image: particle settings]

[image: viewport]

[image: another project with same error]

another project with same error

[image: viewport of alernate project]

Viewport of alternate project

[image]

hair is visible in wireframe mode

Comment: That Blend file access is locked so no one can view it!

Comment: @JohnEason ive updated the link do check it ...

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Please use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for uploading blend files, also please be specific as to what you have done to fix your problem, and clearly describe it for other users. Images of particle settings, the entire viewport, ect, are helpful. :) thanks

Comment: @Timaroberts thank you so much....i will edit and put everything in detail in my question

Comment: Used your blend file. In my Blender 2.90.0 everything looks fine. All thair is emitted from the cube with the subsurf modifier. Maybe an addon messes up something?

Comment: @Blunder will try it thanx for the reply really appreciate it

Comment: @Blunder im having this error with every file

Comment: @Blunder ill upload screenshots of another project of mine ......the same thing happens there too

Comment: I cant reproduce your issue with provided blend file under 2.82 or 2.91 I have access now. Try to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the same problem. I've joined 2 objects (one with a modifier) and separated the meshes again into two objects. This copied a Bevel modifier on the object. The modifier caused the particle origin problem.

Either remove the modifier or tick the checkbox `Use Modifier Stack` in `Emission` → `Source` → `Emit from`.
This solved the issue and the particles are emitted from faces again.

Comment: thanx for the reply mate but im having this error in every single blend file.....So im probably gonna reinstall blender and hopefully that does it

Comment: reinstalled blender its still doing the same thing....btw the hair is visible in the correct spot in wireframe mode and even in a render but not in solid mode

Comment: @RohithEyyani do you have addons installed that could cause this problem? Blender's preferences and addons are stored in the user directory and might be not affected by a re-install of Blender.

Comment: its solved now it was cuz of some addon .....hair tool or hairTG...now that ive disabled it its fine....its working now.....thanx mate for the help

Comment: @RohithEyyani Happy to here you solve it, but ...Why did you marked the answer as solution for you, when your issue was an addon?

Answer (score 0):

Hello everyone I just started using blender And i encountered this problem. I downloaded the human model from sketchfab and I do not think I have any hair add on installed. Please can someone hep me out.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/138543)